# Visual Studio Alt-Copy in Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, copy-paste

Visual Studio has the ability to copy arbitrary blocks of text (not across lines) by holding the alt-key...Is there anything similar in Eclipse?

Thxs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - Look for the "Toggle Block Selection" command (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). That switches the editor between column mode and line mode.

You can make rectangular selections and even type on several lines at once. Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse 3.5 M5 and above, the block selection mode can be toggled using the toolbar icon highlighted bellow

[image]
<sub>(source: [vasanth.in](http://www.vasanth.in/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/eclipse-tip-block-selection-mode.png))</sub>

or using the shortcut key *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is known as Block Selection and is available in Eclipse since 3.5.  Here is a blog article detailing it's usage

- http://www.vasanth.in/2009/03/31/eclipse-tip-block-selection-mode/